# vb.net datagridview calculation based on category

Tags: vb.net

How can I calculate the item price based on the category? Currently, I only can calculate the total value. What is the coding in order to do that?

[image]

**Update**:

Below is the code:

```
Public Class OrderCart
    Private Sub OrderCart_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

        Dim Price As Double
        Dim index As Integer

        'calculate total price
        For index = 0 To dgvCart.RowCount - 1
            Price += dgvCart.Rows(index).Cells(5).Value
        Next
        lblTotalPriceOutput.Text = FormatCurrency(Price)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBackToHome.Click
        Home.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCheckout_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheckout.Click
        Payment.Show()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click
        Dim i As Integer
        'Dim index As Integer

        If (dgvCart.RowCount <= 0) Then
            MessageBox.Show("No item is selected!", "Remove Item",
                       MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Else
            i = dgvCart.CurrentCell.RowIndex
            dgvCart.Rows.RemoveAt(i)

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        dgvCart.Rows.Clear()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: How did you calculate the "Total Price"  for each row? You probably should keep track of the total for each category as well. What you use to store that information may depend on how many categories you have and/or if you expect more categories to be added later. For example, `decimal totalCookware = 0;`, `decimal totalCookingUtensils = 0;`, `decimal totalCutlery = 0;`, `decimal totalKnives = 0;`. You could also use a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Dim Price As Double
        Dim index As Integer

        'calculate total price
        For index = 0 To dgvCart.RowCount - 1
            Price += dgvCart.Rows(index).Cells(5).Value
        Next
        lblTotalPriceOutput.Text = FormatCurrency(Price)

Comment: Please edit your original post and add the code there as an "update". Did you manually add the data to the DataGridView or did you bind it to something such as a [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-6.0)?

Comment: Price += dgvCart.Rows(index).Cells(5).Value - This coding is to calculate all the values in the column, but now I want to calculate based on each category, but I cannot I figure out how to arrange the item based on the category, and after I arrange it how to calculate only that category.

Comment: Am I correct to update the code? First time asking question at here.

Comment: This coding is for picture page one. I add the data into the dgv from another page, I created a group box, and there are the item no, name, category, quantity, price that allows user to select, then the user can click add to cart, then the data will add in into this dgv as you see.

Comment: Before your `Price += dgvCart.Rows(index).Cells(5).Value` line, just add an IF block, something like `If dgvCart.Rows(index).Cells("yourCategoryColumnName").Value = "Cookware" Then` etc.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am trying now

Comment: The problem is solved, thank you guys for helping me.